# How to group air void air and cave air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`execute unless air ~ ~ ~` doesn't work when you're in the void or in a cave.

Is there something like `#air` that joins all air blocks together, like `#wool`?

Comment: the void doesnt have blocks. That's why its the void! Maybe check if they're below 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to an `#air` tag available in vanilla Minecraft.

One possible workaround is to simply duplicate the condition:

```
execute unless block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air unless block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:cave_air run <...>
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly test for `void_air` as of Minecraft 1.16, as `execute unless block` will always fail in the void.

In theory, it should also be possible to create a [predicate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Predicate) in a datapack that tests for the relevant criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own tags to blocks.
If you know datapacks you can add your own tag in **.minecraft/saves/(worldname)/datapacks/(datapackname)/data/(datapacksubname)/tags/blocks** (stuff between brackets isn't specific text). You have to create a .json file named whatever you want the name of the tag to be. In the file you write the following:

```
{
 "values":[
  "air",
  "cave_air",
  "void_air"
 ]
}
```

That should do it, then you can use #(tagname) in game.

Even if you don't know datapacks, you can just follow the file order I gave you, for example:
**.minecraft/saves/(worldname)/datapacks/airgrouping/data/airgrouping/tags/blocks/air.json**